# Printing Dictionary Key if Values were found in CSV List

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, md5, apache-tika

I'm pretty new to python, so forgive me if this is a long explanation to a simple problem.  I need some help in understanding how to use a dictionary to find matches from csv list, then print the key in a reporting type output.

**Goal:** I have a list of clear text privacy data like Social Security Numbers. I need to compare the hash of that clear text and at the same time, obfuscate the clear text to the last 4 digits (XXX-XX-1245). If there is a match from my clear text hash, to a hash I already have in a CSV lookup, I do a mini report linking demographic information of who the found hash might belong to. Also, because nothing is easy, in the mini report needs to print the obfuscated SPI value.

**output should look like this if hash I just generated, matches the hash of column 2 in my spreadsheet:**

```
user@gmail.com Full Name Another Full Name xxx-xx-1234  location1 location2
```

**Problem**: All of the hash, obfuscation, and matching is done and stored in lists and works correctly. I need help figuring out how to print the key from the dictionary with my other columns below without printing the whole set each time in the for-loop.

This works outside of my reader:

```
 for i in hashes_ssnxxxx:
        print(i)
```

but I do not know how to take that value and put it in my print statement inside of the reader.

```
clear_text_hash = [] #Where Hash of clear text value found is stored
obfuscate_xxxxssn = [] #Where obfuscated SPI found by using re.sub is stored

#Zip them in a dictonary to keep the two related
hashes_and_ssnxxxx = dict(zip(obfuscate_xxxxssn,clear_text_hash))

book_of_record = open('path\to\bookofrecord.csv', 'rt',  encoding='UTF-8')
a1 = csv.reader(book_of_record, delimiter=',')

for row in a1:
    hashes = row[2] 
    if hashes in hashes_ssnxxxx.values():
        print(row[16], row[6], hashes_ssnxxxx.keys(), row[13], row[35], row[18], row[43])
```

**UPDATE [Solved]**
using the list comprehension suggested by @tianhua liao all it needed was:

```
if hashes in hashes_ssnxxxx.values():
     obfuscate = [k for k,v in hashes_ssnxxxx.items() if hashes == v]
     print(row[16], obfuscate, row[6], row[13], row[35], row[18], row[43])
```

Comment: Might I say, that perhaps you have not modeled your problem correctly. Based on the fact that the hash maps to a obfuscated SSN, it might make more sense to have the dictionary as hash (key) -> obfuscated SSN (value). That way you can simply check for existence of key and print the value by looking up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I am not sure what your problems really are. If you could give us some simple examples of `hashes_ssnxxxx` and `hashes` will be good.

Here I just give some guessed answers.
After you judge that `if hashes in hashes_ssnxxxx.values():`, you want to print some relative key from `hashes_ssnxxxx.keys()` instead of all of them.

Maybe you could use some **list comprehension** to do that simply. Just like

`[keys for key,vals in hashes_ssnxxxx.items() if hashes == vals]`

The output of that code is a list. If you want to make it more readable, maybe you need to use some index`[0]` or `','.join()` to print it.

Comment: You are the best!! Thank you so much!! This works exactly like I needed it to. I just had to change the key and vals to v and k.